# Difficult Gradle multiproject build for given structure

Tags: java, gradle

I need to setup a Gradle multiproject java build with a fixed build folder.

The structure needs to be like this:

```
--projectRoot/
----build/ (shared for both subprojects)
----javaApp1/
----javaApp2/
```

After the build there should be two shell scripts for starting the applications:

```
--projectRoot/
----build/
------javaApp1
------javaApp2
------libs/
--------javaApp1.jar
--------javaApp2.jar
```

so far my settings.gradle is in the projectRoot:

```
rootProject.name = 'com.example.project'

include 'javaApp1'
include 'javaApp2'
```

and the build.gradle in the projectRoot:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    buildDir = new File(projectDir, "../build")
}

subprojects {
    group 'com.example.project'

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'application'

    dependencies {
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
}
```

with this I'm already able to build from the projectRoot and with `gradle installDist` I get the wanted shell scripts in `projectRoot/build/install/javaApp1/bin/javaApp1` but not in the build folder directly.

So to recap: the shell scripts should end up in `projectRoot/build`.

Comment: Why do you need to use the same build directory for multiple projects? Seems like an XY problem.

Comment: okay yes it should be enought if just the shell scripts and the jars are in the build folder and can be executed in there